# How to create a Likes button that counts the number of clicks from each visitor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blogger

I saw the "likes" function in [this demo blog](http://uno.thebasicpage.com/) and I'm trying to create a similar button. It seems that once hovering over this heart button, there will be a "finish" class added to the div containing it, so there must be a JavaScript that counts each like. I'd like to make it store each like per visitor (not more) on mouse click and remember it when reloading the page (so I guess there should be a cookie as well?).

Comment: You need to send a request from JS to your server which records the like in a datastore. You can then request the number of those records from the datastore as needed. Because of this, your question is far too broad.

Comment: Please show us your code or create a fiddle, where we can reproduce your issue and see your research effort. Unless you do, we can only guess. This is not a general discussion forum. --- Please see the help on how to post good questions!

Answer (score 0):

It's done with ajax which store data to DB without page refresh and updates the value +1 at the same time

Answer (score 0):

### index.html (HTML File)

```
<html>
<head>
 <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="btn">Like</button>
</body>
</html>
```

### script.js (Javascript File)

```
window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener("click",
                  function(){
                   sendLike();
                   document.getElementById("btn").disabled = true;  
                  });
}

function sendLike(){
  var xhr;
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest) xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  else xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  xhr.open("GET","like_counter.php?like=1",true);
  if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
    //handle what you want to do after the operation is completed here
  }
  xhr.send();
}
```

### like_counter.php (PHP File)

```
<?php
 if(!(isset($_GET['like'])&&$_GET['like']==1)){
   die("Access denied!");
 }

 //This is just a demo. On a more practical situation,
 //you would want to store the likes in a database and verify the authenticity
 //of the request to prevent Cross-Site-Request-Forgery
 session_start();
 if(!isset$_SESSION['likes']) $_SESSION['likes'] = 0;
 $_SESSION['likes'] += 1;
 echo "done";
?>
```